# New Employee Production Scale

Tags: management, human-resources

I work in data entry and need to create a production scale for new employees.  If a veteran employee is expected to key 30 items an hour, what’s an acceptable percentage for a new employee to key?

Comment: This isn't really answerable.  It depends heavily on the organization and what you're entering.  Some organizations and items will get much easier with time and an experienced person will be able to enter them twice as fast as a new person.  Other items will have basically no learning curve and the new person would be just as fast as the experienced person.  The best approach is usually to look at what new people have historically done and measure accordingly

Comment: If senior employees will realize things are screwed up enough to facepalm at management once an hour, newbies will facepalm at least once a day; accelerating to similar speeds as the veterans after a few coffee break chats confirm their initial impressions were not just correct but an understatement of how messed up things actually are.

Answer (score 10):

**There should be no production scale if this is how you are coming up with it**

Asking random internet strangers to give you a formula to score employees means that you/your organization doesn't really know how this particular job function works. You evidently have been tasked with creating an evaluation system for the sake of it and your organization is fine with that evaluation system being arbitrary and based neither on operational experience or evidence.

- Go spend a day doing the job to find an answer to your question.
- Go ask whoever does the training for data entry at your organization to find an answer to your question.
- Go poll your current data entry employees and ask them for a number to answer your question.
- Go look at historical entry speeds. If you do not have these, start tracking new hires and see where they start and where they peak and what the curve of speed improvement looks like. If required, sit there all day with a watch and clipboard and count what the new employees do in an hour compared to the experienced ones. And then wait a few weeks and gather the same stats on the same employees.

There are so many things that could impact the rate at which they enter data, from the learning curve of the software they are entering it into to the complexity of the information to how repetitive it is or whether the words/units/whatever are familiar and commonly used or highly domain-specific.

Employees deserve better than an arbitrary evaluation formula based on guesses and internet theories.